# Initialize a class with an array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, c++11, initialization

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass(double *v, int size_of_v){
        /*do something with v*/
    };
};
```

**My question**: Is there any way, I can initialize such class without defining an *array of double* and feeding it to the constructor?

I would like to do something like:

```
auto x = MyClass({1.,2.,3.}, 3);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is called [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) and you need a [std::initilizer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) constructor, that to be achieved in your `MyClass`.

```
#include <initializer_list>  

class MyClass 
{
    double *_v;
    std::size_t _size;
public:

    MyClass(std::initializer_list<double> list) 
        :_v(nullptr), _size(list.size())
    {
        _v = new double[_size];
        std::size_t index = 0;
        for (const double element : list)
        {
            _v[index++] = element;
        }

    };

    ~MyClass() { delete _v; } // never forget, what you created using `new`
};

int main()
{
    auto x = MyClass({ 1.,2.,3. }); // now you can
    //or
    MyClass x2{ 1.,2.,3. };
    //or
    MyClass x3 = { 1.,2.,3. };
}
```

Also note that providing `size_of_v` in a constructor is redundant, as it can be acquired from [std::initializer_list::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/size) method.

And to completeness, follow rule of [three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

---

As an alternative, if you can use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), this could be done in a much **simpler** way, in which **no manual memory management** would be required. Moreover, you can achieve the goal by **less code** and, no more **redundant** `_size`  member.

```
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>    

class MyClass {
    std::vector<double> _v;
public:    
    MyClass(std::initializer_list<double> vec): _v(vec) {};
};
```

Comment: This class breaks the rule of 0/3/5. And why not use a `std::unique_ptr<double[]>`. Or more simply a `std::vector`.

Comment: @MikeVine Just added the alternative. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Well you can use std::vector instead the double*v & it would fit perfectly for your goal

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass(vector<double> v){
        /*do something with v*/
    };
};
```